# Does Twilio stop supporting LINE in the twilio channel?

Tags: twilio, line, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm new here, trying to integrate twilio and LINE app, but find out that the LINE app just disappeared from Twilio channel in the console.

I read some articles on the internet about how to integrate twilio and LINE and they mentioned Twilie channel, I guess that is not the right way to do it now ?

what I'm trying to do is let an agent to communicate with an user by sending LINE messages just like two normal people would do in life, just not private account but an official LINE channel.

Can anyone give me any advice about integrating twilio and LINE, any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio does not currently support LINE. There was some support in the past, but the integration has been closed down for now.

Comment: Thank you! Then I need to work on this in another way

Comment: Another question, do you support audio call from LINE ?

Comment: I believe an audio call from LINE would require an integration with LINE too, which we do not have.